# текст выходит за экран

Tags: html, css, css3, текст, display

текст `$ri['description']` из тега `<p>` выходит за рамки блока и экрана монитора:

```php
<body width="100%" id="body">
<?php
if($_GET['id']!=null){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $idresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id='$id'");

    while($ri = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresult)){ ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $ri['image']; ?>" id="img" >
            <div id="div">
                <h1><?php echo $ri['name']; ?> </h1>
                <p><?php echo $ri['description']; ?></p>
                <p style="font-size: 35px;"><?php echo  $ri['price']; ?> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</body>
```

Вот весь css этой касающийся к этому:

```css
        #body{
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #div{
            height: 500px;
            margin-top: -500px;
            margin-left: 52%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #img{
            margin-top: 250px;
            width: 500px;
        }
        p{
            white-space: normal;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое